# Android M: Canvas strokeWidth and strokeStyle issue while drawing arcs

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-6.0-marshmallow

For the following custom view :
If stroke width is 0.01 then in Android M and and pre-M devices(ex:lollipop)

[image]

However If stroke width is 0.0f then in Android M and and pre-M devices(ex:lollipop)

[image]

Are there changes in stroke width in Android M that should be considered ?
Is there a dependecy between Stroke style and stroke width ?

XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <com.example.testspeedtestgui.TestView
                    android:id="@+id/testView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
                    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code that implements speedometer.java is shown below :

```
package com.example.testspeedtestgui;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TestView extends View {

    private Paint outerLogoPaint;
    private Paint centerOuterPaint;
    private Path outerLogoEdge;


    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        initDrawingTools();

    }

    private void initDrawingTools() {

        float strokeWidth=0.01f;
        centerOuterPaint=new Paint();
        centerOuterPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        centerOuterPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        centerOuterPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        centerOuterPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        centerOuterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        RectF rect = new RectF();
        float angle = getSemicircle(0.025f,0.5f,0.975f,0.5f,rect);
        outerLogoEdge = new Path();
        outerLogoEdge.moveTo(0.025f, 0.495f);
        outerLogoEdge.arcTo(rect, angle, 180);
        outerLogoEdge.moveTo(0.025f, 0.495f);
        outerLogoEdge.lineTo(0.2f, 0.495f);
        //Edge surrounding the lower part of outer semi circle(Logo edge Init) Logo edge Init
        angle = getSemicircle(0.20f,0.5f,0.80f,0.5f,rect);
        outerLogoEdge.arcTo(rect, angle, 180);
        outerLogoEdge.moveTo(0.975f, 0.495f);
        outerLogoEdge.lineTo(0.8f, 0.495f);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float scale = getWidth();
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        drawLogo(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

    }

    private void drawLogo(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawPath(outerLogoEdge, centerOuterPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    public float getSemicircle(float xStart, float yStart, float xEnd,
            float yEnd, RectF ovalRectOUT) {

        float centerX = xStart + ((xEnd - xStart) / 2);
        float centerY = yStart + ((yEnd - yStart) / 2);

        double xLen = (xEnd - xStart);
        double yLen = (yEnd - yStart);
        float radius = (float) (Math.sqrt(xLen * xLen + yLen * yLen) / 2);

        RectF oval = new RectF(centerX - radius,
                centerY - radius, centerX + radius,
                centerY + radius);

        ovalRectOUT.set(oval);

        double radStartAngle = 0;
        radStartAngle = Math.atan2(yStart - centerY, xStart - centerX);
        float startAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(radStartAngle);

        return startAngle;

    }


}
```

From the code **TestView.java** ,  centerOuterPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth) seems to cause the issue.

This is part of my app module and doesnt work on Android M. Tested on  Nexus 5 running Android 6.0 .

source code at https://github.com/vyshas/SpeedometerTest

Comment: so you already did debug your code?

Comment: @pskink yes I did ....

Comment: and did you notice what happens if you use smaller scale in `onDraw`? 100 for example?

Comment: @pskink this worked on the same device running lollipop but on android m it renders incorrectly.  Why would scaling change on the new OS version ?

Comment: because the why you are using Canvas API is strange, odd and bizarre (why everything uses [0..1] coordinates) ???

Comment: There maybe many ways to draw a speedometer and move the needle and this im sure this is one way because I have seen  many do it. Now we have requirements to place speedometer at a particular position on the screen ,etc and do other stuffs that I can't reveal here.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, what i know however is that the way you are drawing on the Canvas is definitely **WRONG**

Comment: OK, so could u point me a link or where I have gone wrong then ?

Comment: just use pixel coordinates, like every drawing code does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89657/discussion-between-vyshakh-amarnath-and-pskink).

Comment: Could you post the full source?

Comment: @powder366 : I did post the full source

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath I thought as a project, so one could load it into Studio without problem... (github)

Comment: @powder366 URL containg source code is added to github..This is eclipse project and not android studio.

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath Can u tell how edge has been attached..?

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath Please can u look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030923/how-to-close-the-stroke-edges-in-canvas-paint

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here:

1. Never use `canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);` Instead just use `canvas.save()`.

> Note: if possible, use the parameter-less save(). It is simpler and
>   faster than individually disabling the saving of matrix or clip with
>   this method.

2. You are drawing everything at microscopic level in the range of (0...1). And then you are scaling it up nearly a hundred folds. This is bad. `canvas.scale()` should not be used this way. Instead try drawing your elements at the normal scale itself.

   You can use `canvas.getHeight()` and `canvas.getWidth()` to get the `height` and `width` of the view you have. Based on this detail, draw the `arc` and the `line`.

Comment: I'll try to do the changes u mentioned but I still don't understand why is it happening only for android m devices ?

Comment: 5 years later and I'm facing similar issue with emulator set to API level 16. I'm drawing a scene where world space coordinates are between 0 and 10, do canvas.scale to fill the screen and setup paint with `1/scale` (~0.01 ballpark) to keep final stroke 1dp wide. Because I haven't found more direct way to keep stroke width unscaled. Sure I can massage numbers to have them appear bigger for drawing but why is this a problem at all? Is it documented anywhere? What is the minimum stroke width that is guaranteed to work correctly?